# Update QR when matrix left-multipied with diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $A$ and its $QR$-factorization, $A = QR$.

Now I need to find the $QR$-factorization of $DA$, where

1. $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
2. $D$ is a diagonal matrix where just one
   element differs from the rest.

Is there a way to reuse the previously computed $QR$ of $A$?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.

The reason for this opinion is a kind of inductive reasoning.

It is a known fact that (see [http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/math/luul2qr.html](http://home.utah.edu/%7Enahaj/math/luul2qr.html)), QR factorization of $A$ is linked to Cholesky factorization of $A^TA$, as displayed by this Matlab program:

```
A=rand(4)
[Q,R]=qr(A)
S=A'*A;
r=chol(S)
q=m*inv(r)
```

that will show you that (q,r) is identical to (Q,R), up to sign changes. In this way, there is a sort of equivalence between:

Finding an "easy" way to take advantage of the QR factorization of $A$ to find a QR factorization of $DA$

and

Finding an "easy" way from Cholesky factorization of $A^TA$ to Cholesky factorization of: $(DA)^T(DA)=A^T(D^TD)A$.

But I dont see how it is possible, because the insertion of a diagonal matrix $D^TD$ deeply modifies the structure of  $A^TA$.

Another remark: *Left*-multiplying by the diagonal matrix $D=diag(a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n)$ amounts to multiply the $k$-th row of $A $ by $a_k(k=1 \cdots n)$, whereas right multiplication yields, *column* -multiplication of $A$'s columns by the $a_k$s, and this is very easy to tackle.

Comment: I have googled with the keywords "QR decompositon update". One gets interesting results (but I have not found something identical to your issue, even by adding the keyword "premultiplier"). Could you say a little more about your motivations for asking this (interesting) question ?

Comment: I can't speak to OP's motivation, but if a solution existed, it would allow for reusing a QR decomp of design matrix X , thus greatly speeding up IWLS in fitting generalized linear models

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your point 1, I agree with Jean Marie.

Your point 2 should be doable:

- Delete from the $QR$ factorisation the row of $A$ corresponding to the element of $D$ which is different from the rest (see, e.g. [qr_delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr_delete.html));
- Multiply the resulting $R$ by the scalar which is the common element of $D$;
- Re-insert the deleted row multiplied by the correct coefficient (see, e.g. [qr_insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr_insert.html)).